# Would a device's dynamic ip change when someone (me) is connected to it by ssh

Tags: networking, ssh

If i where to know what the ip address of my computer, raspberry pi etc was and made a connection to it. would the isp change my ip address? or does this happen when there is no traffic?

Answer (score 0):

dynamic ips actually changes after a lease time expires,which is configured by the network admin. means your ips will change automatically after a certain amount of time. also the dhcp server will automatically lease your ip to other host,if your device or devices is not connected or if your device does not respond to the request of the dhcp server.